# Self-host remote git repository on Windows server

Tags: windows, git

We have a computer on our local network designated as 'the server', that runs Windows XP, where we keep the shared folders and stuff that should be visible to all.

How do I create a remote Git repository on it, and setup it so different people on different computers on the local network can pull/push?

I don't care which protocols are used - `http://`, `ssh://`, `file://`, `git://` are all fine.

Comment: Set up a shared drive. All Git needs is a place where it can write files. @user1562655 The windows machine definitely doesn't need Git installed on it...

Comment: So there is no actual server? I.e. every Git instance will just write into the shared files and in effect just use the server as a file server. What about conflicts, etc., if several client computers try writing to it at once? Is it handled? What about protocols like `git:/`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit:** I recently found about [Bonobo Git Server](http://bonobogitserver.com/) - it is a free and open-source Git Server for Windows and IIS, licensed with an MIT license. I haven't tested it myself yet, but you can give it a try.

There is also this CodeProject article - [Step by Step Setup Git Server on Windows with CopSSH + msysGit and Integrate Git with Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296398/Step-by-Step-Setup-Git-Server-on-Windows-with-CopS)

---

**Old answer:** In the end, I did as @meagar suggested - I created a shared folder on the server, and I followed [this tutorial](http://elegantcode.com/2011/06/18/git-on-windows-creating-a-network-shared-central-repository/), the part about using Git Gui. **Note** that we use pushd/popd because CD does not support UNC paths:

```
pushd \\remote-pc\SharedDocs\MyRemoteGitRepo1
git init --bare
popd
```

Now all you need to do is connect your local repo to remote one. **Note** that you need to use forward slashes for `git remote add origin`, or it won't work:

```
cd C:\Workspace\MyLocalGitRepo1
git remote add origin //remote-pc/SharedDocs/MyRemoteGitRepo1
```

And finally you can push your work to the remote repo:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: hm.. I've never thought of it that way, but, actually, windows net shares provide basic file locking. I mean, when the file is open for writing by one client, others will be rejected and will have to wait. Git's "bare" repositories are designed for a direct file-system based access and it would be quite strange if they were not designed for parallel access by many clients. It does not have to be robust, a single "traditional" lockfile at the root would be sufficient, so I'd be quite surprised if hadn't worked! (and I'm sure the support for such use is far more robust than that! :))

Comment: Yes, besides, from what I found on the Internet, setting up a working Git server on Windows (actual server, using `git:/` or `ssh:/`) is "not for the faint of heart".

Comment: FYI: I used msys fr a while, but later I switched to "Git Extensions" package. It provides a git client, a UI started either separately or Explorer integration (so called git-cheetah, tortoise-like). The UI is much better than in msys. Core and lookalike are the same, but they got it much further than msys package. Package also contains plugins for all VisualStudio versions. And also has "git bash" which is minimalistic Bash shell, really useful, you don't need cygwin/etc. All free, all almost one-click install. Ok, maybe 5 clicks. Cn easily configure it to use KDiff3 if you have it installed.

Comment: Oh, if I was not clear - it does not replace a server. Git extensions are a "user" package, all clientside, so Bonobo's still useful here. I'm just suggesting you to check out the GitExtensions. However - as they are **very** similar to msys in many places (they are even based on it if I remember well), you might need to uninstall msys beforewards, to be sure that nothing clashes or mixes with each other.. Once I got both of them installed (separate msys package plus full git-ex) and it was pretty confusing as all the windows had the same look, but configuration was separate..

Comment: I could simplify this using just Git Shell and a trick of doing "Drive letter and semicolon" (eg. M:) to switch the drive before cd into the repo folder on UNC path. Then git init --bare inside Git Shell. Come back to local repo on C: and add remote and push.