# How to create a remote server on LAN instead of using GitHub?

Tags: git, lan, collaboration, git-bash

Can I create my own remote server instead of using GitHub?

i.e Can I make a remote server on LAN where 3 computers are sharing a drive on a network to do the collaborative work using Gitbash?

Comment: This question is not off-topic, setting up a local network git server is a valid programmer's question. I've asked it myself, but it was for Windows specifically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873297/self-host-remote-git-repository-on-windows-server/18890410#18890410

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to do this

1. Host internal repositories like [Gitlab](http://gitlab.com) or [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash). This will be similar to services like BitBucket or GitHub
2. If you want to have a simple service with SSH authentication - user3159253 has already answered that
3. A very bare bones way is

   1. server: Create a bare repo: `mkdir -p RepoName && git init RepoName --bare`
   2. server: Start the git daemon: `git daemon --base-path=$PWD/RepoName`
   3. client:
      Add your remote: `git remote add origin git://server.url.or.ip/RepoName`
      or just clone it: `git clone git://server.url.or.ip/RepoName`

Comment: To be clear, where you've said `git remote add RepoName ...`, that  is not the name of the repo, i.e. the project, but the name of the remote. "origin" not "helloworld-prog", for example.

Comment: Nope:

git clone git://192.168.0.12/gitrepo
Cloning into 'gitrepo'...
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /gitrepo

Comment: The `access denied or repository not exported` happened to me because, `--base-path` should be `$PWD` instead of `$PWD/RepoName`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do. Actually you need a SSH-service and git would perfectly work over SSH. Since you're on Windows, see [Setup a Git server with msysgit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a remote repository and make it accessible through any of the [protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html) it supports. The AAA would be handled by the transport.