# How to setup Git on local network?

Tags: git, lan, offline-mode

I downloaded Git setup and trying to setup for computers in my network. I searched for the process but I found it for to host code on line on github.com. I found a few links but there is not the whole process.

I am aware for how to push and pull.

Comment: What do you mean by `whole process`? Do you need the command to setup a server and clone the repo?

Comment: I installed GIT now I want create one central repository and access it via my other computers. But I don't how. I am aware for how to push and pull only

Comment: Which protocol do you want to use? There are http, ssh and git available, which all have different properties.

Comment: http will be batter because I am aware it than other.

Comment: Did you ever found out how to do it ? I am searching for the same thing. As someone with no knownledge at all of git, it is hard to find anything that starts from the beginning and has ALL the steps explained

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**To create a new repository**

1. Create directory using git bash or create manually
2. User following commands to create repository

   ```
   cd /repo/path/projectname.git
   git init --bare
   ```
3. After initialize directory share the directory and grant all permission to local group

**To create a local workspace**

4. Create another local repository for local user or other computer use following commands in same order

   ```
   cd ~/workspace/local/path

   git init

   git clone user@gitserver:/path/to/your/folder

   git add origin repo/path 

   git add .

   git status

   git commit
   ```

Comment: what does repo/path on add origin refer to? i cant seem to make it work it always error

Comment: @Roi did you get anywhere with this? Having the same issue.

Comment: @Notts90 yes! basically your git repo should always be "bare" then you clone that repo as a working branch to your working computers

Comment: what software do I need on the server ? what software do I need on the development PC ? How to make them find eachother ? There are no answers in here, only more questions. Is there really no documentation that will help someone that has no knowledge at all of git that can get him started ?

Answer (score 14):

If you're asking about how to connect to a repository hosted by another computer on the same network, take a look at [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273826/creating-a-remote-server-on-a-lan-instead-of-using-git-hub).

Basically, you'll want to use [git daemon](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon). If you just need to set up a single repository, that's one line from each machine:

**Server**:

```
git daemon --base-path=/path/to/repo --export-all
```

**Client**:

```
git remote add LocalServerName git://<serveraddress>/
```

or

```
git clone git://<serveraddress>/
```

where `<serveraddress>` is some reference to that machine (IPv4, IPv6, .local, etc.). You can also specify --verbose for the `daemon` command for more detailed output.

I think, also, you could have `--base-path` point to a folder with many repositories, and that would let you specify which project you wanted on the client-side like so:

```
git daemon --base-path=/path/to/all/repos

git remote add ServerName git://<serveraddress>/MyProject/
```

Be advised: using --export-all will let any computer on the network pull from your repo.

Comment: [jack@nasa git]$ git daemon --base-path=/home/jack/git --export-all
[11067] Could not bind to 0.0.0.0: Address already in use

Answer (score 9):

You have to create a repository on the server side. Go to the folder which should be the repository and execute:

```
git init --bare
```

Then you have to clone the repository on your client with:

```
git clone user@gitserver:/path/to/your/folder
```

Watch [this](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) for further information.

Answer (score 4):

##### create a server folder [repository] with `.git` extension in [computer 1]

```sh
mkdir folder.git
cd folder.git
git init --bare
```

##### in another computer in your network [computer 2]

```sh
mkdir myApp
cd myApp
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin alex@195.185.1.65:/home/alex/folder.git
git push origin master
```

- replace `alex` with the name of your username
- replace `195.185.1.65` with your IP address from server computer

##### any computer in your network can access the repository [folder.git]

```sh
git clone alex@195.185.1.65:/home/alex/folder.git
```

- this is going to download a directory with the name `folder`, just like if you were doing it from GitHub.

###### assumptions

- `git` uses **ssh** protocol by default for connecting between computers.
- you can setup **ssh** by doing `ssh alex@195.185.1.65` from remote computer, and it's going to ask you for permission to connect, write **yes**. I think it's just easier than to copy your **public key** to the server **authorized key** file at `/home/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
- remember to replace `alex` with your **username**, also `195.185.1.65` with your IP address.

from source [Git--Setting Up the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Answer (score 1):

It is just easy as 1, 2, 3, 4:

1) Go to folder, where you want to initialize server(e.g: `c:\temp`).

2) Open `git bash` in this folder.

3) Type:

```
git init projectName --bare   // e.g => git init test --bare
```

well,You’ve just set up your server!

4) Choose where you want to initialize client repository and open `git bash` there.

Type:

```
git clone path/projectName  // e.g => git clone c:/temp/test
```

> IMPORTANT! DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE BACKSLASH (`\`) IN THE PATH TO
>   DIRECT SLASH(`/`).

You can use this repository as usual and open it with your favorite git client.

**connect to this server from another computer in local network:**

(in windows 7) Firstly go to Control Panel > Network And Sharing Center > Change advanced sharing settings.
Tick turn on network discovery.

Then go to folder where you have set up server and share it with users that you want to give permission for accessing it.

then Type:

```
git clone //ip/projectName   // e.g => git clone //192.168.11.125/test
```

I hope is useful.

Comment: git is not recognized as an internal command. Please is there no documentation that has ALL the steps ?

Comment: @GuidoG, the main command is `git init projectName` with option `--bare` , that `--bare` Create a bare repository. If GIT_DIR environment is not set, it is set to the current working directory. the other steps is normally commands.

Comment: and what software do I need ? I don't have git yet. I don't want to use git on the internet, I need git here at my local network and it should never ever connect to internet. So what do I need from software and how does it works ?

Comment: @GuidoG, the top solution only needed to install the `git`, ofcourse you can use the offline git server. for example `Bonobo Git Server` (for windows os). use this link for download: `https://bonobogitserver.com/`. download and create new website in local server and copy the downloaded file to your website and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

From [JJ-Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929708/jj-brown)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441041/6309)

> Basically, you'll want to use git daemon.

For that, make sure to use Git 2.32 (Q2 2021): "[`git daemon`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bde35a2a9334b27451d2cd7b175f9cafa7e68598/Documentation/git-daemon.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon))</sup> has been tightened against systems that take backslash as directory separator.

See [commit 9a7f1ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a7f1ce8b78dae09cf4510a98bd6b81d0d478772) (25 Mar 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bde35a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bde35a2a9334b27451d2cd7b175f9cafa7e68598), 08 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`daemon`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a7f1ce8b78dae09cf4510a98bd6b81d0d478772): sanitize all directory separators
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When sanitizing client-supplied strings on Windows, also strip off backslashes, not just slashes.