# SourceTree: create local repository for coworker

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using GIT to track a local directory. I would like to share the repo with a coworker on the same LAN. Is it possibile to achieve this without using GitHub or a remote repo? Is there a way to allow my coworker to access my repo (with pull requests?)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the approaches may vary depending on the OS and whether you want to give him just read (fetch/pull) or also write (push) access.

Comment: The OS would be Mac OS X (on both machines). We could start with only read access, and later moving to write access.... Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Git on local network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827831/how-to-setup-git-on-local-network)

Comment: Actually the solution was to create on the same machine a brand new  '--bare' repository, add remote to the other one (using file:/// as "url") and, sharing the SSH access on the Mac preferences, allow the other Mac to access the repository (using my machine credentials, so be careful!)