# How can I clone a Git repository from a Lan's PC with credentials

Tags: git, clone

I have installed Git on my computer. But I still can't find a way to clone Git repository from another machine on the same Lan network. GIT GUI doesn't provide away to fill in the credentials. (Git for Windows)

How can I achieve this?

Example :

```
git url : \\LAPT0\master-git
username : gUser
password : gPass
```

Comment: Will this help? Use `ssh` and it should ask for the password automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827831/how-to-setup-git-on-local-network

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a local file URL for that path:

```
git clone file:////LAPT0/master-git
```

This assumes that `master-git` is the share name. I would personally recommend though putting the Git repository into another folder inside of the share.

As for the credentials, it’s best if you open the share *first* in Windows Explorer so that Windows will ask you for the credentials at that point. And then all connections to the share should work without you having to provide those again, until you restart your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically
 to clone repo with credentials is:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

In your case that the repo in other machine in the LAN, the Git repo in the other machine need to execute this command:

```
git init --bare
```

Then you have to clone the repository on your machine with:

```
git clone user@gitserver:/path/to/your/folder
```