# Coding together on the same project as a team from different locations

Tags: git, share, dropbox

I have tried Git and Dropbox a few years ago and it worked but doesn't work this time, or I may have forgotten the procedure, I have tried searching online for this to no avail. Are the other ways we can collaborate or better still if there are others ways to go with Git and Dropbox.

Comment: Can you explain further what isn't working for you? Why is git not going to work for your project?

Comment: Well, the point here is it was my first time trying to collaborate online with a friend in another city. We ended up using bitbucket and it works perfectly, as the same process can be replicated on GitHub and other repositories.

Answer (score 1):

To set up a git server on your local network look at this question: 
[How to setup Git on local network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827831/how-to-setup-git-on-local-network)

Otherwise, I would recommend you simply use a git hosting service as there are many that offer free use if you make your repositories public. If you must have private repositories and really don't want to pay for cloud service, you can use the above method.